# Pull to refresh inside a scrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

Is it possible to implement "pull to refresh" inside a scrollview.

Comment: Short answer yes, just google it.

Comment: Thanx. But I got code only for a tableview. I am looking for a normal scrollview

Comment: A tableView is just a scrollview with some extra properties. Thus the same code should work., but without code or post [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) your question isn't more then just a code request. Some thing that is not welcome on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks. These links helped me.

https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh

http://mt.gomiso.com/2012/03/22/yet-another-pull-to-refresh-library/

https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh

Comment: +1 for your own answer and show the greatitute to SO that it actually helps you in solving.

Answer (score 6):

There's a good article here:

http://mt.gomiso.com/2012/03/22/yet-another-pull-to-refresh-library/

Gives you a few different ways to implement it.

Comment: The link is not active anymore

Comment: I updated the link, now it's working again

Answer (score 1):

Please try https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh with scrollview; I believe it is good to go with minimal chances.

Also look at the http://www.altinkonline.nl/tutorials/xcode/uitableview/pull-down-to-refresh/ which is very good step by step guide that helps you to build what you want. Just Replace UITableViewController  with UIscrollview in that step by step guide and you will have good stuff in your hand.

Hope it helps.
Jigar

Comment: second link is broken